# postgres trigger creates index: BEFORE INSERT ON hides one row

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.4

I have a trigger `AFTER INSERT ON mytable` that calls a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        index TEXT;
    BEGIN
        index := 'myIndex_' || NEW.id2::text;
        IF to_regclass(index::cstring) IS NULL THEN
            EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' || index || ' ON mytable(id) WITH (FILLFACTOR=100) WHERE id2=' || NEW.id2|| ';';
            RAISE NOTICE 'Created new index %',index;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
SECURITY DEFINER
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION myfunction()
    OWNER TO theadmin;
```

This works wonderfully. For each distinct `id2` I create an index. Speeds up relevant queries by a lot.

As mentioned above I trigger this `AFTER INSERT ON`. Before doing that however I had the trigger set to `BEFORE INSERT ON`. And the function did some strange things. (Yes, I had changed the `RETURN NULL` to `RETURN NEW`)

- insert of a new row `insert into mytable VALUES(1391, 868, 0.5, 0.5);`
- creates the corresponding index `myIndex_868`
- the inserted row **does not appear** in mytable when doing a select :(
- trying to insert the same row results in `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mytable_pkey"` because of course `DETAIL:  Key (id, id2)=(1391, 868) already exists.`
- inserting other rows for the same id2 works as expected :)
- `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = 1391 and id2 = 868` does nothing
- `DROP INDEX myIndex_868;` drops the index. And suddenly the initial row that never appeared in the table is suddenly there!

Why does `BEFORE INSERT ON` behave so differently? Is this a bug in postgres 9.4 or did I overlook something?

Just for completeness' sake:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
AFTER INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE myfunction();
```

vs.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE myfunction();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd argue that this is a bug in PostgreSQL. I could reproduce it with 9.6.

It is clear that the row is not contained in the index as it is created in the `BEFORE` trigger, but the fact that the index is not updated when the row is inserted is a bug in my opinion.

I have [written to pgsql-hackers](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B53A4DC9A@ntex2010i.host.magwien.gv.at) to ask for an opinion.

But apart from that, I don't see the point of the whole exercise.
Better than creating a gazillion indexes would be to create a single one:

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable(id2, id);
```

Comment: would that cover all my queries for id2?`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id2=$1` used to be very slow, now with an index for each WHERE clause it is fast.

Comment: For that, an even simpler index would be better: `CREATE INDEX ON mytable(id2)`.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I was under the impression that I need one index per WHERE clause. Also I'm sorting my results by id. `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id2=$1 ORDER BY id;` and the index speeds that up immensely.

Comment: Well, then use the index I gave in my answer. Try it, you'll see that it is just as fast. And those many indexes will create a headache for you during query planning and other things.

Comment: Thank you! That's so much easier :)